# How to refresh ListView after Sorting in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, listview

I have a ListView which contains my customers. This ListView currently is a Stateless Widget. After sorting the list of customers inside the parent, I need to refresh the list.

parent where the List is displayed (Parent is stateful):

```
MyLieferListe(
  bestellungen.anzahlPositionen,
  bestellungen.kunde,
  notifyParent: refresh,
),
```

MyLieferListe (currently Stateless):

```
SingleChildScrollView(
            child: ListView.builder(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    getBeleg();
                    this.notifyParent(kunden[index]);
                  },
                  child: MyBestellungText(
                      kunden[index].kundenbezeichnung,
                      kunden[index].kundenNr,
                      "${kunden[index].strasse}, ${kunden[index].plz} ${kunden[index].ort}",
                      kunden[index].tourHinweis),
                );
              },
              itemCount: kunden.length,
            ),
          ),
```

How to refresh the ListView of the Child which is displayed inside of the parent?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you have to make your list stateful because on changing the list. You have to call setState.

A bad solution would be to use Navigator.pushReplacement.

A good solution would be to make your list a stateful widget.

Answer (score 0):

A state change triggers a rebuild in Flutter, so in order to ensure your widget rebuilds after you sort the list, you should call `setState`

```dart
// a state variable
List<Kunde> kunden;

onSortButtonClick() {
    List<Kunde> newKunden = kunden.sort(...);
    
    // store to the state
    setState((){
        kunden = newKunden;
    });
}

build(WidgetContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(/* use kunden, from state, in here */)
}
```

As you mention, your parent is already stateful. You should move `bestellungen.kunde` to the state variables (set it first in `initState` and use `setState` every time you change it), then it should automatically rebuild widget if you update `kunden` via `setState`.

Alternatively, you could make the child widget stateful and put kunden in the state of that widget. Theoretically, that should be slightly better since you then *only* rebuild the child, not the parent, but it realistically shouldn't make much difference in this case.